# How to write a recursion function for all the possible parameter combinations in python

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

I am trying to write a piece of code to traverse all the possible parameter combinations for a algorithm with python.

```
import numpy as np
parameter={'alpha1':np.linspace(0.3,0.4,10),'alpha2':np.linspace(0.9,2,100),...'alpha5':np.linspace(5,10,100)}
```

the problem is that I just couldn't write 5-nested for loop.Can anyone give a demo on how to write a recursion function to give a list of all possible combinations of the parameters?
Thanks

Comment: First, are you just doing this to learn recursion? Because if not (a) you don't usually want to do either deep recursion _or_ iteration on NumPy arrays, and (b) if you do, there are easier (and more efficient) ways to write this—see the `itertools` docs.

Comment: Meanwhile, show us the code you'd write for a simpler problem that just needed a fixed and small number of nested loops, like 2 or 3, and it'll be easier to show you how to turn that into a recursive solution that works with a dynamic or large amount of nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `itertools.product` function, which takes a list of iterators and creates the iterator of their cartesian product (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)).

In my solution I use the values from the `parameter` dictionary as the iterators. I go over the product of the options for each key (`for values_option in product(*parameter.values())`) and create a new dictionary with the original keys)

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

parameter={'alpha1':np.linspace(0.3,0.4,10),'alpha2':np.linspace(0.9,2,100)}

def parameter_options(parameter):
    for values_option in product(*parameter.values()):
        yield dict(zip(parameter.keys(), values_option))

for opt in parameter_options(parameter):
    print opt
```

---

Let's go over this piece by piece:

**`parameter.values()`**

This gives a list of the values for each key-value in the dictionary.

For example, if we have `dictionary = {a: (1, 2, 3), b: (4, 5, 6)}`, using `dictionary.values()` will return `[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]`. Doing `dictionary.keys()` will give `['a', 'b']`.

*Note*: There's a difference here between Python 2 and Python 3 - in Python 2 these methods (`keys()` and `values()`) will return normal lists, whereas in Python 3 they return a special iterator. This shouldn't change the solution.

**`product(*parameter.values())`**

We use the asterisk to "unpack" lists. Simply put, `itertools.product` receives any number of arguments. We want to use all the `values` as input:

```
vals = parameter.values()
product(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], ..., vals[len(vals)])
```

Python has an easy way to pass lists as input to functions that receive an arbitrary number of arguments. This last line is the same as `product(*vals)`.

**`for values_option in product(*parameter.values()):`**

We go over all the options for the values of the `parameter` dictionary.

The first iteration will give the first option for all arguments. The second iteration will give the first option for all but one argument, which will have its second option. This goes on all the way until we have the last option where each argument has its last option.

**`zip(parameter.keys(), values_option)`**

This takes the two lists (of keys and possible values) and basically transposes them. it gives a list of the same length which includes pairs: the first element from the first list and the second from the second list. Like so:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
zip(keys, vals) = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

**`dict(...)`**

Now we can use this zipped list to create a dictionary. This is a different way to initiate a dict

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} == dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

**`yield ...`**

This is what we use in python to create iterators. It's a complicated subject but instead of this you could write before the `for` loop this line

```
options = []
```

and instead of `yield dict(...)` write `options.append(dict(...))`.
and in the end of the function `return options`.

Voila.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explaination, sorry for the late reply since last week was buried in a terrible project. I tried your code with 3 parameters and it's great to see the results!

Comment: do you know how the Cartesian product in itertools are implemented? by recursion?

Comment: You can check the implementation in the documentation (linked in my answer). It's a for loop which acts recursively.